# pChart - GUI and Local Windows Use

Tags: php, charts

I normally use LaTeX to create high quality charts. I found pChart ([link](http://www.pchart.net/)) and was wondering.

- Is there a GUI in order to use the library?
- I never used PHP - maybe somebody can point me a to a "Hello World" for a setup to use pChart.
- Can I use pChart on a Windows 7 PC "standalone" (not o a server) - maybe as a portable software?

> Maybe something like XAMPP can be used to have it all local?

Comment: pChart looks to me like a complex set of Web interfaces that you'd use primarily to generate chart images on a Web page. While I haven't looked too deeply at the library, I'd expect you to need a server to run it, since it looks like it expects you to use the Web, and for that you'd need a server running PHP. PHP as a language can be run from the command-line, but this is a plugin for a PHP server.

Comment: @NathanOliver: This has nothing to do with LaTeX. I just wanted to add that I have knowledge about LaTeX but amlost no knowledge about PHP.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Sorry My mistake.  From my first glance I thought This was talking about adding pChart to LaTex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 The closest thing to a GUI for pChart is the sandbox system http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.sandbox.html

2 The installation guide is loaded here: http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.installation.html with instructions how to access the examples here http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.examples.html

3 No, pChart is a PHP library, therefore it must be run on a web server. You could possibly generate charts using the PHP command line but I doubt it would be very easy.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe something like XAMPP can be used to have it all local?

Comment: @ManuelKuehner You could use XAMPP to use it locally. You may have to install extra extensions for PHP though, I cannot remember off the top of my head which it requires.